# Why can I only vote 37 times?

Tags: support, voting

I just have voted 37 times and wanted to upvote a new answer but I'm not allowed to do. Message: `Daily vote limit reached` I would understand this if the number would be 40, but 37?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The vote limit is a bit more complex than that, but is in the [FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation). You have up to 40 votes per day, but ten are reserved for questions. So you can only upvote up to 30 answers per day. Moreover, you can't just upvote 30 answers followed by 10 questions: once you hit the voting limit on answers, that's it for the day. So you have to be voting in a 'balanced' way, for a mix of questions and answers, to get to 40.

Comment: On the other hand: We wan't people to vote on quetions a lot! :) I mean, vote up, or ask the OP in the comments to make the question better, so that you can vote it up later :)

Comment: @tohecz Why is there an emphasis on voting for questions?

Comment: @ScottH. It seems to be under-estimated. Everybody votes on useful answers, but people tend to forget that asking the correct questions is the key to the knowledge! Notice that [the only "voting" golden badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/44) is about voting on questions.

Comment: @tohecz Good point about the badge, thanks.