# Adding information for upvoted questions and answers per day separately

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, voting

In my question [Why can I only vote 37 times?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/why-can-i-only-vote-37-times), Joseph Wright answered that there is a rule saying that I can only upvote 30 answers per day.

Looking in the FAQ I found a short explanation (with the first look I oversee this):

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach
>   the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions.

I found no place where I can see how many answers I upvoted today and how many questions. Even not in the summary profile, which only shows the complete voting per day (answers and questions together).

Because this rule is important I suggest to display somewhere on the page the actual status of upvoted questions and answers per day separately. That could be, for example, in the summary profile for the votings or near user name or received bagdes in the headline.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the motivation behind this is to make you upvote questions more in general, just like the [Electorate badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate) encourages upvoting of questions. Giving you a counter that tells you "I've already upvoted enough questions, so now I can upvote answers" would be beside the point here.

However, if you really wanna keep track, you could go to your profile and check the "votes" tab ⇒ upvotes (not taking downvotes into consideration here). This doesn't directly tell you which ones were on questions and which ones on answers, but if you mouseover the link and check the target URL, you can tell:

That's an answer:

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72801/how-do-i-make-the-sections-un-numbered/72830#72830
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/xxxxx/bla-bla-bla/yyyyy#yyyyy
```

That's a question:

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/framed-or-mdframed-pros-cons
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/xxxxx/bla-bla-bla
```

But you'll have to count manually.