# Non correspondence between the total votes and the numbering indicated in the orange rectangle

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

My simple question is this. If the number indicated below indicates the daily votes assigned to me, why do I have three votes remained? So I'll never get to 40 total votes. 
Is the problem because I vote positively from 2018?

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly 40 is the maximum number of votes possible. After 25 (or so, I don't remember the actual number) votes the remaining votes are recalculated based on the ratio of votes on answers to votes on questions. If you voted more on questions, you get extra votes (up to a maximum that gets you to no more than 40).

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90726, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90202, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279724

Comment: @moewe In summary, are some votes for high reputation subtracted? :-( But I like to vote.

Comment: This is not about high reputation. One post explained it like this: You get 30 votes that you can spend on questions *and* answers and 10 votes that can only be cast on questions. So if you only vote on questions you get up to 40 votes, if you only vote on answers you get 30.

Comment: @moewe Can, please, you add an answer that I upvoted :-)? Thank you very much.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2703/35864, would you agree?

Comment: @moewe If my question is a duplicate, now I close my question.